# \xrdef and \xref in eplain

Tags: cross-referencing, tex-core, eplain

I tried to upgrade `eplain` used in the book "TeX for the Impatient" from version 1.9 to latest version 3.6, but came across the following problem with new `eplain`.

The follwing code could be compiled with `eplain` 1.9 but not with `eplain` 3.6:

```
\input eplain
define at \xrdef\input and refer to \xrefn\input done
\bye
```

The error message is as follows:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=xetex 2014.5.27)  5 OCT 2014 19:20
entering extended mode
**xrefn.tex
(E:\test\xrefn.tex
(E:\test\eplain.tex
Requested font "logo10" scaled 1000
Requested font "logosl10" scaled 1000
Requested font "line10" scaled 1000
Requested font "cmtt8" scaled 1000
)
! I can't find file `}'.
<to be read again> 
                   \global 
\readauxfile ->\if@auxfiledone \else \global 
                                             \@auxfiledonetrue \@testfileexi...

\definexref ...f}{#1}\edef \temp {#1}\readauxfile 
                                                  \edef \@wr {\noexpand \wri...

\xrdef ...definexref {#1}{\noexpand \folio }{page}
                                                  \endgroup \endgroup \ignor...
l.5 define \xrdef\input
                        and refer \xref\input done
Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<to be read again> 
                   \global 
\readauxfile ->\if@auxfiledone \else \global 
                                             \@auxfiledonetrue \@testfileexi...

\definexref ...f}{#1}\edef \temp {#1}\readauxfile 
                                                  \edef \@wr {\noexpand \wri...

\xrdef ...definexref {#1}{\noexpand \folio }{page}
                                                  \endgroup \endgroup \ignor...
l.5 define \xrdef\input
                        and refer \xref\input done
*** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)

No pages of output.
```

How could I resolve this problem?

Comment: older eplains are available here, if that's an option: ftp://tug.org/historic/macros/eplain/

Comment: it gives an error `! I can't find file '}{'.` with eplain 2.1 which is the oldest version at the tug site. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle these two commands are used for page references. `\xrdef` should define a label named `\input`, and `\xrefn` refer to the page number of that label.

Comment: `xrdef` expects as argument a string; I don't think `\input` is the ideal. It may have worked in older versions, but this doesn't mean you should have used it.

Comment: @egreg But It seems `eplain` 1.9 could automatically convert the token '\input` to a string.

Comment: Most probably Karl Berry and the other maintainers decided that this wasn't a good choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need this for coping with old files, you can do this way

```
\input eplain

\catcode`@=11
\def\stringify#1{%
  \expandafter\let\csname zh@\string#1\endcsname#1%
  \def#1##1{%
    \begingroup\def\temp{##1}%
    \edef\x{\endgroup
      \expandafter\noexpand\csname zh@\string#1\endcsname{%
        \expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\temp}%
    }\x
  }%
}
\stringify\xrdef
\stringify\xrefn
\stringify\@definelabel
\catcode`@=12

define at \xrdef\input and refer to \xrefn\input

define at \xrdef{xyz} and refer to \xrefn{xyz}
\bye
```

However it's definitely a bad idea using a symbolic token as argument to `\xrdef`.

This is what appears if the `.aux` file has not yet been updated:

[image]

and here what results after the second run of TeX

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'm wondering is it valid to include your code into my translation of the book "TeX for the Impatient", which is GPL licensed?

Comment: @Z.H. No, don't; as I said, it's a hack for reading older files, but in newer ones the argument to `\xrdef` should be a string. There are various reasons for this choice, one of which is that so doing you can even use a macro in the argument to represent a variable string; this would be impossible with the hack.

Comment: Is it possible to remove the extra space after control sequence names?

Comment: @Z.H. Possible, yes; convenient, no.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure this works in general, but works here (delete any existing `.aux` file first)

```
\input eplain
%\input eplain-2.1/eplain
\let\oldxrdef\xrdef
\def\xrdef#1{\expandafter\oldxrdef\expandafter{\string\string\string#1}}
\let\oldxrefn\xrefn
\def\xrefn#1{\expandafter\oldxrefn\expandafter{\string#1}}

define at \xrdef\input and refer to \xrefn\input done
\bye
```